# Как указать attributes вложенной ассоциации в Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

У меня есть 4 сущности.

1. Библиотека
2. Книга
3. Автор
4. Профиль автора

Мне нужно получить список всех книг, в нужной библиотеке и вернуть еще инфу об авторе.
Пример:

```
Book.findAll({
            where: {library: 1},
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'name',
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.User,
                    as: 'author',
                    foreignKey: 'authorId',
                    include: [{
                        model: db.UserProfile,
                        as: 'profile',
                        foreignKey: 'userId',
                        attributes: ['name']
                    }],
                    attributes: [
                        'id',
                        'email'
                    ],
                    raw: true
                }
            ],
        }).then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })
```

Это вернет мне:

```
[
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "book name",
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "author_username",
                "profile": {
                    "name": "Author Real Name"
                }
            }
        }
      ]
```

Вроде все ок, но я хочу чтобы у меня в объекте `author` не-было ключа `profile`, а просто выводилось `name`.

Я делаю что-то вроде:

```
Book.findAll({
                where: {library: 1},
                attributes: [
                    'id',
                    'name',
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.User,
                        as: 'author',
                        foreignKey: 'authorId',
                        include: [{
                            model: db.UserProfile,
                            as: 'profile',
                            foreignKey: 'userId',
                            attributes: []
                        }],
                        attributes: [
                            'id',
                            'email'
                            [Sequelize.col('profile.name'), 'name']
                        ],
                        raw: true
                    }
                ],
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err)
            })
```

На что получаю вроде логичную ошибку.

```
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'author.profile.name' in 'field list'",
```

Собственно вопрос - как это победить?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Вдруг кому-то поможет:

```
....
include: [
                    {
                        model: db.User,
                        as: 'author',
                        foreignKey: 'authorId',
                        include: [{
                            model: db.UserProfile,
                            as: 'profile',
                            foreignKey: 'userId',
                            attributes: []
                        }],
                        attributes: [
                            'id',
                            'email'
                            [Sequelize.literal('`author->profile`.`name`'), 'name']
                        ],
                        raw: true
                    }
.....
```